# SQL: How to alter a table's column that has a reference in a View

Tags: sql, view, alter

I have a View that references multiple tables. I need to increase the length of a varchar column of one of these tables. As this column is used in View i get the following error while running Alter query for this column:

> The object 'VW_ViewName' is dependent on column 'Column_To_Modify'.
>
> Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
>
> ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN
> Column_To_Modify failed because one or more objects access this
> column.

Do i have to drop and create the View again to alter the column OR there is some easier work around ?

Comment: Have you checked the Object Dependencies for that View? You clearly have some other database object that is using that view and column. You'll need to amend that object first before changing the view.

Comment: Remove the reference, do alter then reestablish the reference.

Comment: @JonathonOgden: The column has reference to that View. I have checked that. if i drop the view then i am able to execute alter column query successfully.

Comment: @Esty: How can i remove the reference ?

Comment: just drop the view.